# Paramter as File path in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I just starting with DataStage, developing a project to process files I'm getting an strange error when the variable is mapped from a sequence job to parallel job,  if I check the path in the error message the path exist and the file is there.. Any insight that can help to solve this problem. I'd really appreciate.. Below you can see with the pictures how the job is implemented and the error.

Thanks in Advance

[image: job]
[image: gettingAllFileName]
[image: loop]
[image: variable]
[image: SqquenceJobVariableTopassAParameter]
[image: parallelJobParameter]
[image: FilePath]
[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The white space between your file path and the : in the error message are suspicious. Copy the file path directly from the log and paste into an editor that you can do character examination. You are likely having whitespace issues when looking to the path.

Comment: Hi William Pearsall, I thought exactly like you, even I implemented a trim function to remove trailing whitespaces, but it didn't worked. I create a parallel job parameter and copied the path with whitespace and it worked. So, I'm confuse with this error, BDW share with me a way to delete this trailing whitespace.. Thanks

Comment: I use a slightly different looping mechanism to avoid this in my jobs. I do a simple ls statement for the pattern I want. then I execute the following dcount(Execute_Command_8.$CommandOutput,@FM) and loop from 1 to count. File name is field(Execute_Command_8.$CommandOutput,@FM,StartLoop_Activity_2.$Counter), but the last entry will be blank, so you need to do a catch for it with a nested condition.

Comment: Hi, Willian Pearsall, Thanks for sharing that with me, I've trying to do it step by step your recommendation, but I didn't get it.. Can you share with me those print screen to see it.. I'd appreciate.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please indicate what you are doing to the file path in the User Variables activity. The log appears to contain a valid Windows pathname, and reports "no such file or directory". Can you please validate that the file does indeed exist at that location?  If it does not, then your ls | awk | tr pipeline or your sequence parameter TestFile_$DestinationPath may need some work.

Comment: Hi Ray Wurlod, Yes the file exists at the location, if I copy and paste the path in the error the file open, it means that ls command and the user variables are working perfect. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Just to verify - although the path exists -  it has to be at the server where DataStage is installed and not on the client...

Comment: Hi MichaelTienfenbacher, it's in the server even if a pass the parameter from the parallel job not coming from the sequence job it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation where the file name being passed from the sequencer to the job looks to resolve correctly, but it gives the same error of file not found.  Even though I copy the resolved name (taken from job log of the job) and open that path/file, it opens successfully.  However, you do not see that DS is adding an extra "space" to the end of the resolved parameter value in the job.  If you were to switch the input file stage from specific file to file pattern and just add * to the end of your file name, you will see that DS is trying to resolve the parameter value plus a space plus an *.  For example, your sequencer is passing file name as "D:\abc.txt", but the job will see it as "D:\abc.txt *".

Actual job log entry of the job is:

ls: File or directory "D:\abc.txt *" is not found

The fix that worked for me is to do an Exchange of "0D" to "FF" in the User Variable stage.  For some reason, DS was adding a carriage return in the User Variable stage.  I wrote the file name to a text file to see what the value is being passed along the way and it always showed up as the correct value with no special characters added throughout my sequencer.  By adding this Exchange in the User Variable expression, it worked for me as what you are expecting (passing the true file name value to the next job and able to read the file successfully).  There is no need to actually switch to file pattern, but this was needed for debugging purposes to see the value actually being resolved in the job.